# syntax near in pivot sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get date in this `format dd/MMM/yyyy`

so i used the following query

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '/')
```

but when i tried to apply it it on below query i got this error msg.

> Error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near ', '.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                      from  dbo.DailySales INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants ON dbo.DailySales.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID

                    group by Name
                    order by Name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SalesDate, 106, ' ', '/') AS [Sales Date],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
  select SalesDate, Restaurants.Name, GrossSales
  from  dbo.DailySales INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants ON dbo.DailySales.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
   WHERE MONTH(SalesDate) = 1 AND YEAR(SalesDate) = 2017 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(GrossSales)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Comment: The problem are the nested single quotes

Comment: SELECT  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SalesDate, 106, '' '', ''/'')

Comment: Chanukya  still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SalesDate, 106), '' '', ''/'')
```

should be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                      from  dbo.DailySales INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants ON dbo.DailySales.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID

                    group by Name
                    order by Name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SalesDate, 106), '' '', ''/'') AS [Sales Date],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
  select SalesDate, Restaurants.Name, GrossSales
  from  dbo.DailySales INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants ON dbo.DailySales.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
   WHERE MONTH(SalesDate) = 1 AND YEAR(SalesDate) = 2017 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(GrossSales)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the single quotes on your dynamic query and the `REPLACE` function

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                      FROM dbo.DailySales INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants ON dbo.DailySales.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
                    group by Name
                    order by Name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SalesDate, 106), '' '', ''/'') AS [Sales Date],
    ' + @cols + ' 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SalesDate, 
            Restaurants.Name, 
            GrossSales
        FROM
            dbo.DailySales 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants ON dbo.DailySales.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
        WHERE 
            MONTH(SalesDate) = 1 AND YEAR(SalesDate) = 2017 
    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        SUM(GrossSales)
        FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '

EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.